# Como acessar o "onDestroy" quando o app é forçado a fechar (force-killed)

Tags: android

Eu tenho um aplicativo e eu preciso que ele acesse um codigo, quando o app é forçado a fechar(force-killed). Abaixo vou deixar o codigo para melhor entendimento, porem ele está no onDestroy e não roda quando o aplicativo é forçado a fechar, justamente o que eu queria!

No entanto, eu preciso que o usuario consiga sair e voltar no app e somente rode o codigo quando ele realmente fecha-lo!

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    //Ao fechar completamente a tela de validação com o campo textValidacao nulo ou incorreto, o cadastro no autenticacao e no banco de dados sao apagados, para evitar o cadastro de usuarios não validados.
    String codigoDigitado = codigoValidacao.getText().toString(); //Pega o texto da caixa de texto8

    if (! codigoDigitado.equals(tokenGerado)) {//Verifica se esse texto e igual, caso ele seja diferente do tokenGerado

        user = UsuarioFirebase.getUsuarioAtual();//Pega usuario atual

        user.delete().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() { //deleta o usuario no Auth
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                if (task.isSuccessful()) {//Testa para ver se funcionou

                    Log.i("Usuario deletado(auth)","Sim");


                }else{

                    Log.i("Usuario deletado(auth)","Não");

                }

            }
        });

        DatabaseReference firebaseRef = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebase();//Excluir registro no realtime database

        final String identificadorUsuarioLogado = Base64Custom.codificarBase64(UsuarioFirebase.getIdentificadorUsuario());//Id usuario

        DatabaseReference usuarioExcluirRef = firebaseRef//Referencia do usuario
                .child("usuarios")
                .child(identificadorUsuarioLogado);

        usuarioExcluirRef.removeValue();//Remove os valores

        DatabaseReference testeOkRef = firebaseRef.child("usuarios");//Acessa o no usuarios

        testeOkRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {//testa se o usuario foi deletado, vendo se ainda existe o identificadorUsuarioLogado no nó usuarios
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(identificadorUsuarioLogado)){//Verifica sem tem o filho no nó

                    Log.i("Usuario deletado(Banco)","Não");
                    Toast.makeText(ValidadorActivity.this, "Usuario deletado(Banco) - Não", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }else {

                    Log.i("Usuario deletado(Banco)","Sim");
                    Toast.makeText(ValidadorActivity.this, "Usuario deletado(Banco) - Sim", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

    autenticacao.signOut();

    Intent i = new Intent(ValidadorActivity.this, CadastroUsuarioActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: _Force-killed_ é a mesma coisa que `kill -9`, é uma ordem para o sistema operacional matar o processo em execução. Pelo que sei é instantâneo e não dá ao processo nenhuma oportunidade de executar `onDestroy()` ou qualquer código que seja.

Comment: Sim, por isso precisava de um método q executasse quando o app foce force-killed

Comment: Leia a documentação do `onDestroy()`,  acredito que ele não dá nenhuma garantia de ser chamado. E nenhum método dará essa garantia.

Comment: Ele não é chamado mesmo, procuro um método similar, porem q execute quando for force-killed. Já estou a procura faz um tempinho vou tentar de outras formar

Comment: Estou falando que não vai achar outro método que dê essa garantia.

Comment: Vou tentar de outra forma aqui, obrigado!